# Generate a keystore for an Android app in the Export Android Application wizard?

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, export, code-signing

I'm trying to export a signed Android application in Eclipse.

I think I'm going in the right direction:

- Right click on project > **Android Tools** > **Export Signed Application Package**
- The Export Android Application wizard appears.
- Select the project I want to export, click **Next**.
- The Keystore Selection screen appears.

It looks like this (forgive my ascii, file uploader not working):

```
[ ] Use existing keystore
[o] Create new keystore

Location: __________ [Browse]
Password: __________
Confirm: __________
```

I don't have an existing keystore, so I click the "Create new keystore" radio button.  The location field remains active, must be filled, and if I browse to some directory I'd like the keystore to go after it's created, the dialog complains that "Keystore path is a directory."

1. Is it actually possible to create a keystore with this dialog?
2. If not, how can I create one?  My google-fu has provided only failed experiments for me so far.  I'm using Eclipse on a PC.

The [Compile and sign with Eclipse ADT](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) section in the android developer page seems to think this will just work out, but I can't get past this part of the dialog.  I can export unsigned .apk files just fine.

Thank you!

Comment: +1 for an ascii drawing of a dialog!

Comment: +10 for ascii drawing

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You should be able to create a keystore with the dialog, yes. After navigating to the folder you want to use, type a name in the 'File name:' field in the file browse window, e.g. `sophie.keystore`. Then you should be able to proceed.

Alternatively, you can create it on the command line as described [in the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#cert).

The command looks like this:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

for example:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/dcaunt.keystore -alias dcaunt -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Comment: I didn't initially have luck with that command but it must've been some kind of user error on my part, thanks for confirming it's the right thing.  I said this below, too, but that `keystorename.keystore` bit was the part I was missing.

Comment: If you're on Windows, try `keytool -genkey -v -keystore dcaunt.keystore -alias dcaunt -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000` (remove the ~/). Otherwise, nevermind, and I'm glad you got it working with Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

If you have created an app right now with the sdk and adt plugin, like the hello world app, then you'll have to chose the `debug.keystore` file while exporting. The files is in `c:/users/.../.android/debug.keystore`, after that when asked for password.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 : How to generate keystore in eclipse**

[image: Step 1 : How to generate keystore in eclipse]

**Step 2: Browse Directory and put filename.keystore and create password**

[[image: Step 2: Browse Directory and put filename.keystore and create password]]

**Step 3: Fill Expiry details and License detail**

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uompr.jpg)[[image: Step 3: Fill Expiry details and License detail]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2kIO.jpg)

***You are done!***