# Android how to sign my APK with google provided license key

Tags: android, apk

I have to sign my `APK` and Google market provide me a key which is something like

> YOUR LICENSE KEY FOR THIS APPLICATION Base64-encoded RSA public key to
>   include in your binary. Please remove any spaces.
>   MIIBIjANBgasdfasdfdaskqhkiG9w0BAQEadfadfasdFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAuacIf........

How can I sign my `APK` with this key and how include this key in my binary?

Comment: Are you using eclipse? If so you can sign your application when you export it.

Answer (score 29):

I had the same question. Finally found that the RSA public key on Dev-Console is for "licensing". It means that the app can use the key to query if the user has a current and valid license for using your app or the services in it. 
**This is totally different from signing an apk.**

http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The key provided by Google is not used in the manor that the question is being asked.

Answer (score 4):

I too am like the original poster asked wondering what to do with the lisence key generated by the developer console on my way to publishing in the Google Play store.

While all the above posts show how to export and create keystore etc in Eclipse or from a command line, none of them answer what the dadgum key Google offers up is for. Do I need to add it somehow? I see no way to specify the key Google generated as a "licening key" in the Google Play Developer Console, and NOTHING tells me HOW to bind THAT key to my app.

I already know how to export a signed app using eclipse but that does not have the Google Play  key. If someone can point me in the right direction it is much appreciated.

OK I have figured it out. The licence key is irrelevant to signing your app and is for licensing purposes within your app.

Comment: have you figured out how we can do it -- " have the license added to the binary" ? I still din't find the answer to the question in the post here.

Answer (score 1):

The Android Developer site has a great walkthrough for signing apps [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#setup).

Seeing as though you have your key, you just need to create a password-protected keystore file  "`.keystore`" by using the keytool shown [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#cert). This will prompt you to enter all the details that Android requires for a signed app.

You can check other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656115/generate-a-keystore-for-an-android-app-in-the-export-android-application-wizard) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997748/how-can-i-create-a-keystore).

Eclipse makes it really easy to export by right clicking on your project and selecting "Android Tools > Export Signed Application Package".

Good luck!

Comment: what is the purpose of the key that google provided me? and how I ll add this in my binary ... I didnt get how to add this key in my binary???